# error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘BIGNUM {aka bignum_st}’ requested

Tags: c++, openssl

I am trying to use the following `openssl` function with `g++` under Linux

```
 int RSA_generate_key_ex(RSA *rsa, int bits, BIGNUM *e, BN_GENCB *cb);
```

as described [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_generate_key.html). My example program is as follows:

```
RSA *rsa;
BIGNUM e = 7;
if (!RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa, 1024, e)) {
   cout << "error" << endl;
}
```

But the error I get during compilation is

```
src/test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
src/test.cpp:29:15: error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘BIGNUM {aka bignum_st}’ requested
src/test.cpp:30:41: error: cannot convert ‘BIGNUM {aka bignum_st}’ to ‘BIGNUM* {aka bignum_st*}’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘int RSA_generate_key_ex(RSA*, int, BIGNUM*, BN_GENCB*)’
make: *** [build/test.o] Error 1
```

I have no idea what `BIGNUM` is, nor is it described on the linked page.

Comment: the third argument expects a pointer to BIGNUM

Comment: And how to create a pointer to BIGNUM? Replacing `BIGNUM e=7;` with `BIGNUM *e=7;` does not really help. Is BIGNUM a class? a function? a primitive..?

Comment: @Alex, The docs suggest that `BIGNUM` is just a type that you operate on by using the `BN_*` functions.

Comment: Now I am lost even more. Can't you fix my code so it works?

Comment: I've never used this library. I'm simply telling you that `BIGNUM` has a C API, where you need to use functions to do anything with it. For example, the name `BN_new` suggests that it might be used to create a `BIGNUM`. I didn't look specifically, so I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: @Alex: Your questions sound lazy. "Can't you just fix it for me?" Can't you spend some time studying the documentation and help material and learn to understand the code you're writing?

Comment: omg 3K+ rep and it's asking to write code for it. nice

Comment: @Abyx: Its much faster... I still have not found a page on which `BN_new()` is explained, for example.

Comment: @Alex https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_new.html

Comment: Why do people downvote? I really do not understand! It's a legitime programming question.

Comment: Already explained why. Just because it's "faster" for you doesn't mean it's good for this site or community in general. Or even good for _you_, in the long run! You are going to have to learn how to perform **research**.

Comment: With your explanation, noone should ever ask a question. Everything can be done by research.  So why does this site exist at all? There are no stupid questions, only stupid answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply it with a `BIGNUM*`.

```
BIGNUM *e = BN_new();
BN_set_word(e, 7);
if (!RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa, 1024, e, cb)) { /* ... */ }
BN_clear_free(e);
```

If you have no idea on how `cb` should be defined, replace it with `NULL`. That is,

```
RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa, 1024, e, NULL)
```

Comment: Your code does not match the declaration of `RSA_generate_key_ex` that the OP supplied both in prose and in the quoted error message.